# Jquery string replace not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace, str-replace

This is driving me mad:

```
// Get the comment template
var comment = $('#CommentTemplate').html();

// Delete all entered text
$("textarea#NewComment").val('');

// Get comments returned ID
var ThisCommentsID = data.substring(2, data.length);
var d = new Date();

// Replace comment variables
comment = comment.replace("{CID}", ThisCommentsID);
comment = comment.replace("{USERNAME}", CurrUsername);
comment = comment.replace("{BODY}", Message);
comment = comment.replace("{GRAV}", GravHash);
comment = comment.replace("{CLEARDATE}", GravHash);
comment = comment.replace("{ISODATE}", ISODateString(d));
comment = comment.replace("{USERURL}", RelURL + CurrUsername);

// Add it
$('#comment-total-wrap').prepend(comment);
```

This basically works 100% fine, dynamically adding a comment to the list with an AJAX query, but all the values on the template are coming out still as {CID}, {GRAV} etc etc.  It's not throwing any errors, the replace isn't working.

I've tried:

```
comment = comment.replace("{BODY}", Message);
```

as well but it still just shows as {BODY} on the output HTML.  Any help appreciated.

The HTML template on the page is:

```
<div id="CommentTemplate" style="display:none;">
    <div id="cid{CID}" class="comment-wrapper">
        <div id="CommentHead" class="comment-head ch-highlight">
            <div class="comment-date">
                <abbr class="timeago" title="{ISODATE}" id="Timeago{CID}">{CLEARDATE}</abbr>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-author">
                Written by <a id="CommentAuthorLink" title="Visit this game makers profile" href="{USERURL}">{USERNAME}</a>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <table class="comment-body" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="100" valign="top" align="center">
                    <a id="GravLink" title="{USERNAME} makes games with Construct 2" href="{USERURL}"><img id="GravatarComment" title="{USERNAME}&#39;s Gravatar" class="comment-avatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{GRAV}?r=pg&amp;s=80" /></a>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div class="comment-txt">
                        {BODY}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="clear"></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using str=str.replace , right as it has to store ...the latest value.

Comment: It's behaving weirdly, it replaces the body fine, but none of the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try this

```
comment.replace("{CID}", ThisCommentsID);

try this

comment= comment.replace(/\{CID\}/gi, ThisCommentsID);
```

Comment: No luck, doesn't seem to do anything, as you put it throws errors `; expected` and enclosed in quotes it doesn't perform any replace action

Comment: Perfect! +1!!!!!  Could you explain to me why this works please?  What was I doing wrong?

Comment: @Tom , just with espace sequence we have to tell that string starts and string ends...  \{    \}  ...

Comment: It should be worth mentioning that this fixes the problem because the replace command expects a Regular Expression, and will treat a string as such - which for plain letters tends to work just fine, but the curly braces have special meaning in a regex.

Comment: i tried this

var output = "1{hi}2";
output.replace("{hi}", "something");

and it worked... go figure

Answer (score 0):

just use `comment = comment.replace("{BODY}", Message);` and it should work.

Comment: It doesn't, that's why I asked the question :)

Comment: It behaves really weirdly, replaces some of them, other not :(